# Development of MySQL.pas wrapper for Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi, wrapper

**Background:** I want to use the Delphi translation of mysql.c in a project but the original maintainer Matthias Fichtner (http://www.fichtner.net/delphi/mysql/) appears to have taken it down.

**Question:** Does anyone know of a similar wrapper (or an updated version of Matthias Fichtner's wrapper) around *libmySQL.dll* that is similar in lightweight nature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original URL http://www.fichtner.net/delphi/mysql is now redirecting to here: http://www.audio-data.de/mysql.html

This seems to be a MUCH newer version than the one Jim posted.

> **mysql.pas (Version 2009-09-13)**
>
> Client API for MySQL AB`s SQL Database
>   Server using LibMySql.dll or
>   LibMySqld.dll (Embeeded MYSQL Server).
>   It is a Pascal translation of mysql.h
>   and some other C header files needed
>   for writing clients for the MySQL
>   database server.
>
> The unit is tested with:
>
> - Delphi Versions: (3), (4), 5, 6,   2007, 2009, 2010.
>
>   LibMySql.dll Versions: 3.23, 4.0, 4.1, 5.0, 5.1, 6.0
>
>   MySQL-Server Versions: 3.23, 4.0, 4.1, 5.0, 5.1

Comment: Agreed. This looks to be the canonical URL for now, until this one disappears too!

Answer (score 5):

[MySQL.pas](http://www.geocities.com/siazali/mysql5/mysql.pas)

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//                    MySQL Client API for Borland Delphi (version 4 and above)
//
//                           Pascal Interface Unit for libmySQL.dll, the
//                        Client Library for MySQL AB's SQL Database Server
//
//                  This is a literal translation of relevant parts of MySQL AB's
//                    C header files, mysql.h, mysql_com.h, and mysql_version.h
//
//                            Copyright (c) 1999-2002 Matthias Fichtner
//                           (see license.txt for licensing information)
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                       See mysql.h for MySQL AB's copyright and GPL notice
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//       17-Aug-1999  mf  Translated mysql.h                             MySQL 3.22.24
//       19-Aug-1999  mf  Corrected some type definitions                MySQL 3.22.24
//       20-Aug-1999  mf  Finished debugging the unit                    MySQL 3.22.24
//       18-Sep-1999  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.22.26a          MySQL 3.22.26a
//       22-Oct-1999  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.22.28           MySQL 3.22.28
//       02-Jan-2000  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.22.29           MySQL 3.22.29
//       21-Jan-2000  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.22.30           MySQL 3.22.30
//       07-Feb-2000  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.22.31           MySQL 3.22.31
//       16-Feb-2000  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.22.32           MySQL 3.22.32
//       13-Aug-2000  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.22.34           MySQL 3.22.34
//       14-Aug-2000  mf  Reworked entire unit for first 3.23 release    MySQL 3.23.19-beta
//       14-Aug-2000  mf  Added mysql_character_set_name()               MySQL 3.23.22-beta
//       11-Sep-2000  mf  Added IS_NUM_FIELD and INTERNAL_NUM_FIELD      MySQL 3.23.24-beta
//       08-Oct-2000  mf  Modified TMEM_ROOT, enum_server_command,       MySQL 3.23.25-beta
//                        and INTERNAL_NUM_FIELD
//       01-Nov-2000  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.23.27           MySQL 3.23.27-beta
//       25-Nov-2000  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.23.28           MySQL 3.23.28-gamma
//       05-Jan-2001  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.23.30           MySQL 3.23.30-gamma
//       19-Jan-2001  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.23.31           MySQL 3.23.31
//       11-Mar-2001  mf  Added functions mysql_real_send_query(),       MySQL 3.23.33
//                        mysql_send_query(), and mysql_reap_query()
//       28-Mai-2001  mf  Modified mysql_send_query(), removed           MySQL 3.23.38
//                        mysql_real_send_query(), mysql_reap_query(),
//                        added mysql_read_query_result(), and fixed
//                        CLIENT_TRANSACTIONS
//       07-Aug-2001  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.23.40           MySQL 3.23.40
//       23-Sep-2001  mf  Code maintenance for release 3.23.42           MySQL 3.23.42
//       29-Jan-2002  mf  Added libmysql_load(), libmysql_free(),        MySQL 3.23.47
//                        libmysql_status and LIBMYSQL_ constants
//                        for dynamic loading of libmySQL.dll
//       11-Mar-2002  mf  Added MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE to mysql_option   MySQL 3.23.49
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//                   Latest releases of mysql.pas are made available through the
//                   distribution site at: http://www.fichtner.net/delphi/mysql/
//
//                  Please send questions, bug reports, and suggestions regarding
//                  mysql.pas to Matthias Fichtner <mfichtner@fichtner-meyer.com>
//
//                      See readme.txt for an introduction and documentation.
//                    See license.txt for licensing information and disclaimer.
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                     This unit is provided "as is". Use it at your own risk.
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

unit mysql;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INTERFACE
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

uses
  Windows,  // Needed for some type definitions
  Winsock;  // Needed for some type definitions

// ----------------
// From mysql.h ...
// ----------------

type
  my_bool = byte;
  gptr = pChar;

type
  PUSED_MEM = ^TUSED_MEM;  // struct for once_alloc
  TUSED_MEM = record
    next: PUSED_MEM;       // Next block in use
    left: longword;        // memory left in block
    size: longword;        // size of block
  end;

type
  error_proc = procedure;

type
  PMEM_ROOT = ^TMEM_ROOT;
  TMEM_ROOT = record
    free: PUSED_MEM;
    used: PUSED_MEM;
    pre_alloc: PUSED_MEM;
    min_malloc: longword;
    block_size: longword;
    error_handler: error_proc;
  end;

type
  my_socket = TSocket;

// --------------------
// From mysql_com.h ...
// --------------------

const
  NAME_LEN = 64;               // Field/table name length
  HOSTNAME_LENGTH = 60;
  USERNAME_LENGTH = 16;
  SERVER_VERSION_LENGTH = 60;

  LOCAL_HOST = 'localhost';
  LOCAL_HOST_NAMEDPIPE = '.';

  MYSQL_NAMEDPIPE = 'MySQL';
  MYSQL_SERVICENAME = 'MySql';

type
  enum_server_command = (
    COM_SLEEP, COM_QUIT, COM_INIT_DB, COM_QUERY,
    COM_FIELD_LIST, COM_CREATE_DB, COM_DROP_DB, COM_REFRESH,
    COM_SHUTDOWN, COM_STATISTICS,
    COM_PROCESS_INFO, COM_CONNECT, COM_PROCESS_KILL,
    COM_DEBUG, COM_PING, COM_TIME, COM_DELAYED_INSERT,
    COM_CHANGE_USER, COM_BINLOG_DUMP,
    COM_TABLE_DUMP, COM_CONNECT_OUT
  );

const
  NOT_NULL_FLAG = 1;      // Field can't be NULL
  PRI_KEY_FLAG = 2;       // Field is part of a primary key
  UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG = 4;    // Field is part of a unique key
  MULTIPLE_KEY_FLAG = 8;  // Field is part of a key
  BLOB_FLAG = 16;         // Field is a blob
  UNSIGNED_FLAG = 32;     // Field is unsigned
  ZEROFILL_FLAG = 64;     // Field is zerofill
  BINARY_FLAG = 128;

  // The following are only sent to new clients

  ENUM_FLAG = 256;            // field is an enum
  AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG = 512;  // field is a autoincrement field
  TIMESTAMP_FLAG = 1024;      // Field is a timestamp
  SET_FLAG = 2048;            // field is a set
  NUM_FLAG = 32768;           // Field is num (for clients)
  PART_KEY_FLAG = 16384;      // Intern; Part of some key
  GROUP_FLAG = 32768;         // Intern: Group field
  UNIQUE_FLAG = 65536;        // Intern: Used by sql_yacc

  REFRESH_GRANT = 1;     // Refresh grant tables
  REFRESH_LOG = 2;       // Start on new log file
  REFRESH_TABLES = 4;    // close all tables
  REFRESH_HOSTS = 8;     // Flush host cache
  REFRESH_STATUS = 16;   // Flush status variables
  REFRESH_THREADS = 32;  // Flush status variables
  REFRESH_SLAVE = 64;    // Reset master info and restart slave
                         // thread
  REFRESH_MASTER = 128;  // Remove all bin logs in the index
                         // and truncate the index

  // The following can't be set with mysql_refresh()

  REFRESH_READ_LOCK = 16384;  // Lock tables for read
  REFRESH_FAST = 32768;       // Intern flag

  CLIENT_LONG_PASSWORD = 1;      // new more secure passwords
  CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS = 2;         // Found instead of affected rows
  CLIENT_LONG_FLAG = 4;          // Get all column flags
  CLIENT_CONNECT_WITH_DB = 8;    // One can specify db on connect
  CLIENT_NO_SCHEMA = 16;         // Don't allow database.table.column
  CLIENT_COMPRESS = 32;          // Can use compression protcol
  CLIENT_ODBC = 64;              // Odbc client
  CLIENT_LOCAL_FILES = 128;      // Can use LOAD DATA LOCAL
  CLIENT_IGNORE_SPACE = 256;     // Ignore spaces before '('
  CLIENT_INTERACTIVE = 1024;     // This is an interactive client
  CLIENT_SSL = 2048;             // Switch to SSL after handshake
  CLIENT_IGNORE_SIGPIPE = 4096;  // IGNORE sigpipes
  CLIENT_TRANSACTIONS = 8192;    // Client knows about transactions

  SERVER_STATUS_IN_TRANS = 1;    // Transaction has started
  SERVER_STATUS_AUTOCOMMIT = 2;  // Server in auto_commit mode

  MYSQL_ERRMSG_SIZE = 200;
  NET_READ_TIMEOUT = 30;       // Timeout on read
  NET_WRITE_TIMEOUT = 60;      // Timeout on write
  NET_WAIT_TIMEOUT = 8*60*60;  // Wait for new query

type
  PVio = ^TVio;
  TVio = record
  end;

type
  PNET = ^TNET;
  TNET = record
    vio: PVio;
    fd: my_socket;
    fcntl: longint;
    buff, buff_end, write_pos, read_pos: pByte;
    last_error: array [0..MYSQL_ERRMSG_SIZE - 1] of char;
    last_errno, max_packet, timeout, pkt_nr: longword;
    error: byte;
    return_errno, compress: my_bool;
    no_send_ok: my_bool;  // needed if we are doing several
      // queries in one command ( as in LOAD TABLE ... FROM MASTER ),
      // and do not want to confuse the client with OK at the wrong time
    remain_in_buf, length, buf_length, where_b: longword;
    return_status: pLongword;
    reading_or_writing: byte;
    save_char: char;
  end;

const
  packet_error: longword = $ffffffff;

const
  FIELD_TYPE_DECIMAL = 0;
  FIELD_TYPE_TINY = 1;
  FIELD_TYPE_SHORT = 2;
  FIELD_TYPE_LONG = 3;
  FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT = 4;
  FIELD_TYPE_DOUBLE = 5;
  FIELD_TYPE_NULL = 6;
  FIELD_TYPE_TIMESTAMP = 7;
  FIELD_TYPE_LONGLONG = 8;
  FIELD_TYPE_INT24 = 9;
  FIELD_TYPE_DATE = 10;
  FIELD_TYPE_TIME = 11;
  FIELD_TYPE_DATETIME = 12;
  FIELD_TYPE_YEAR = 13;
  FIELD_TYPE_NEWDATE = 14;
  FIELD_TYPE_ENUM = 247;
  FIELD_TYPE_SET = 248;
  FIELD_TYPE_TINY_BLOB = 249;
  FIELD_TYPE_MEDIUM_BLOB = 250;
  FIELD_TYPE_LONG_BLOB = 251;
  FIELD_TYPE_BLOB = 252;
  FIELD_TYPE_VAR_STRING = 253;
  FIELD_TYPE_STRING = 254;

const
  FIELD_TYPE_CHAR = FIELD_TYPE_TINY;      // For compability
  FIELD_TYPE_INTERVAL = FIELD_TYPE_ENUM;  // For compability

type
  enum_field_types = FIELD_TYPE_DECIMAL..FIELD_TYPE_STRING;

// ------------------------
// From mysql_version.h ...
// ------------------------

const
  PROTOCOL_VERSION = 10;
  MYSQL_SERVER_VERSION = '3.23.49';
  MYSQL_SERVER_SUFFIX = '';
  FRM_VER = 6;
  MYSQL_VERSION_ID = 32349;
  MYSQL_PORT = 3306;
  MYSQL_UNIX_ADDR = '/tmp/mysql.sock';

// ----------------
// From mysql.h ...
// ----------------

function IS_PRI_KEY(n: longword): boolean;
function IS_NOT_NULL(n: longword): boolean;
function IS_BLOB(n: longword): boolean;
function IS_NUM(t: longword): boolean;

type
  PMYSQL_FIELD = ^TMYSQL_FIELD;
  TMYSQL_FIELD = record
    name: pChar;              // Name of column
    table: pChar;             // Table of column if column was a field
    def: pChar;               // Default value (set by mysql_list_fields)
    _type: enum_field_types;  // Type of field. Se mysql_com.h for types
    length: longword;         // Width of column
    max_length: longword;     // Max width of selected set
    flags: longword;          // Div flags
    decimals: longword;       // Number of decimals in field
  end;

function IS_NUM_FIELD(f: PMYSQL_FIELD): boolean;
function INTERNAL_NUM_FIELD(f: PMYSQL_FIELD): boolean;

type
  PMYSQL_ROW = ^TMYSQL_ROW;  // return data as array of strings
  TMYSQL_ROW = array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(pChar) - 1] of pChar;

type
  MYSQL_FIELD_OFFSET = longword;  // offset to current field

type
  my_ulonglong = int64;

const
  MYSQL_COUNT_ERROR: my_ulonglong = not 0;

type
  PMYSQL_ROWS = ^TMYSQL_ROWS;
  TMYSQL_ROWS = record
    next: PMYSQL_ROWS;  // list of rows
    data: PMYSQL_ROW;
  end;

type
  MYSQL_ROW_OFFSET = PMYSQL_ROWS;  // offset to current row

type
  PMYSQL_DATA = ^TMYSQL_DATA;
  TMYSQL_DATA = record
    rows: my_ulonglong;
    fields: longword;
    data: PMYSQL_ROWS;
    alloc: TMEM_ROOT;
  end;

type
  PMYSQL_OPTIONS = ^TMYSQL_OPTIONS;
  TMYSQL_OPTIONS = record
    connect_timeout, client_flag: longword;
    compress, named_pipe: my_bool;
    port: longword;
    host, init_command, user, password, unix_socket, db: pChar;
    my_cnf_file, my_cnf_group, charset_dir, charset_name: pChar;
    use_ssl: my_bool;   // if to use SSL or not
    ssl_key: pChar;     // PEM key file
    ssl_cert: pChar;    // PEM cert file
    ssl_ca: pChar;      // PEM CA file
    ssl_capath: pChar;  // PEM directory of CA-s?
  end;

type
  mysql_option = (
    MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, MYSQL_OPT_COMPRESS,
    MYSQL_OPT_NAMED_PIPE, MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND,
    MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_FILE, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP,
    MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_DIR, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME,
    MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE
  );

type
  mysql_status = (
    MYSQL_STATUS_READY, MYSQL_STATUS_GET_RESULT,
    MYSQL_STATUS_USE_RESULT
  );

type
  PMYSQL_FIELDS = ^TMYSQL_FIELDS;
  TMYSQL_FIELDS = array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(TMYSQL_FIELD) - 1] of TMYSQL_FIELD;

type
  PCHARSET_INFO = ^TCHARSET_INFO;
  TCHARSET_INFO = record
    // Omitted: Structure not necessarily needed.
    // Definition of struct charset_info_st can be
    // found in include/m_ctype.h
  end;

type
  PMYSQL = ^TMYSQL;
  TMYSQL = record
    net: TNET;                    // Communication parameters
    connector_fd: gptr;           // ConnectorFd for SSL
    host, user, passwd, unix_socket, server_version, host_info, info, db: pChar;
    port, client_flag, server_capabilities: longword;
    protocol_version: longword;
    field_count: longword;
    server_status: longword;
    thread_id: longword;          // Id for connection in server
    affected_rows: my_ulonglong;
    insert_id: my_ulonglong;      // id if insert on table with NEXTNR
    extra_info: my_ulonglong;     // Used by mysqlshow
    packet_length: longword;
    status: mysql_status;
    fields: PMYSQL_FIELDS;
    field_alloc: TMEM_ROOT;
    free_me: my_bool;             // If free in mysql_close
    reconnect: my_bool;           // set to 1 if automatic reconnect
    options: TMYSQL_OPTIONS;
    scramble_buff: array [0..8] of char;
    charset: PCHARSET_INFO;
    server_language: longword;
  end;

type
  PMYSQL_RES = ^TMYSQL_RES;
  TMYSQL_RES = record
    row_count: my_ulonglong;
    field_count, current_field: longword;
    fields: PMYSQL_FIELDS;
    data: PMYSQL_DATA;
    data_cursor: PMYSQL_ROWS;
    field_alloc: TMEM_ROOT;
    row: PMYSQL_ROW;          // If unbuffered read
    current_row: PMYSQL_ROW;  // buffer to current row
    lengths: pLongword;       // column lengths of current row
    handle: PMYSQL;           // for unbuffered reads
    eof: my_bool;             // Used my mysql_fetch_row
  end;

// Functions to get information from the MYSQL and MYSQL_RES structures
// Should definitely be used if one uses shared libraries

var
  mysql_num_rows: function(res: PMYSQL_RES): my_ulonglong; stdcall;
  mysql_num_fields: function(res: PMYSQL_RES): longword; stdcall;
  mysql_eof: function(res: PMYSQL_RES): my_bool; stdcall;
  mysql_fetch_field_direct: function(res: PMYSQL_RES; fieldnr: longword): PMYSQL_FIELD; stdcall;
  mysql_fetch_fields: function(res: PMYSQL_RES): PMYSQL_FIELDS; stdcall;
  mysql_row_tell: function(res: PMYSQL_RES): PMYSQL_ROWS; stdcall;
  mysql_field_tell: function(res: PMYSQL_RES): longword; stdcall;

var
  mysql_field_count: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): longword; stdcall;
  mysql_affected_rows: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): my_ulonglong; stdcall;
  mysql_insert_id: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): my_ulonglong; stdcall;
  mysql_errno: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): longword; stdcall;
  mysql_error: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): pChar; stdcall;
  mysql_info: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): pChar; stdcall;
  mysql_thread_id: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): longword; stdcall;
  mysql_character_set_name: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): pChar; stdcall;

type
  PMYSQL_LENGTHS = ^TMYSQL_LENGTHS;
  TMYSQL_LENGTHS = array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(longword) - 1] of longword;

type
  extend_buffer_func = function(void: pointer; _to: pChar; length: pLongword): pChar;

var
  mysql_init: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): PMYSQL; stdcall;
  {$IFDEF HAVE_OPENSSL}
  mysql_ssl_set: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const key, cert, ca, capath: pChar): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_ssl_cipher: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): pChar; stdcall;
  mysql_ssl_clear: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): longint; stdcall;
  {$ENDIF} // HAVE_OPENSSL
  mysql_connect: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const host, user, passwd: pChar): PMYSQL; stdcall;
  mysql_change_user: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const user, passwd, db: pChar): my_bool; stdcall;
  mysql_real_connect: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const host, user, passwd, db: pChar; port: longword; const unix_socket: pChar; clientflag: longword): PMYSQL; stdcall;
  mysql_close: procedure(sock: PMYSQL); stdcall;
  mysql_select_db: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const db: pChar): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_query: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const q: pChar): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_send_query: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const q: pChar; length: longword): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_read_query_result: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_real_query: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const q: pChar; length: longword): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_create_db: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const DB: pChar): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_drop_db: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const DB: pChar): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_shutdown: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_dump_debug_info: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_refresh: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; refresh_options: longword): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_kill: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; pid: longword): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_ping: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_stat: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): pChar; stdcall;
  mysql_get_server_info: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): pChar; stdcall;
  mysql_get_client_info: function: pChar; stdcall;
  mysql_get_host_info: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): pChar; stdcall;
  mysql_get_proto_info: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): longword; stdcall;
  mysql_list_dbs: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const wild: pChar): PMYSQL_RES; stdcall;
  mysql_list_tables: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const wild: pChar): PMYSQL_RES; stdcall;
  mysql_list_fields: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; const table, wild: pChar): PMYSQL_RES; stdcall;
  mysql_list_processes: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): PMYSQL_RES; stdcall;
  mysql_store_result: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): PMYSQL_RES; stdcall;
  mysql_use_result: function(_mysql: PMYSQL): PMYSQL_RES; stdcall;
  mysql_options: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; option: mysql_option; const arg: pChar): longint; stdcall;
  mysql_free_result: procedure(result: PMYSQL_RES); stdcall;
  mysql_data_seek: procedure(result: PMYSQL_RES; offset: my_ulonglong); stdcall;
  mysql_row_seek: function(result: PMYSQL_RES; offset: MYSQL_ROW_OFFSET): MYSQL_ROW_OFFSET; stdcall;
  mysql_field_seek: function(result: PMYSQL_RES; offset: MYSQL_FIELD_OFFSET): MYSQL_FIELD_OFFSET; stdcall;
  mysql_fetch_row: function(result: PMYSQL_RES): PMYSQL_ROW; stdcall;
  mysql_fetch_lengths: function(result: PMYSQL_RES): PMYSQL_LENGTHS; stdcall;
  mysql_fetch_field: function(result: PMYSQL_RES): PMYSQL_FIELD; stdcall;
  mysql_escape_string: function(_to: pChar; const from: pChar; from_length: longword): longword; stdcall;
  mysql_real_escape_string: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; _to: pChar; const from: pChar; length: longword): longword; stdcall;
  mysql_debug: procedure(const debug: pChar); stdcall;
  mysql_odbc_escape_string: function(_mysql: PMYSQL; _to: pChar; to_length: longword; const from: pChar; from_length: longword; param: pointer; extend_buffer: extend_buffer_func): pChar; stdcall;
  myodbc_remove_escape: procedure(_mysql: PMYSQL; name: pChar); stdcall;
  mysql_thread_safe: function: longword; stdcall;

function mysql_reload(_mysql: PMySQL): longint;

// Status codes for libmySQL.dll

const
  LIBMYSQL_UNDEFINED = 0;     // libmysql_load() has not yet been called
  LIBMYSQL_MISSING = 1;       // No suitable DLL could be located
  LIBMYSQL_INCOMPATIBLE = 2;  // A DLL was found but it is not compatible
  LIBMYSQL_READY = 3;         // The DLL was loaded successfully

var
  libmysql_handle: HMODULE = 0;
  libmysql_status: byte = LIBMYSQL_UNDEFINED;

function libmysql_load(name: pChar): byte;
procedure libmysql_free;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IMPLEMENTATION
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function IS_PRI_KEY(n: longword): boolean;
begin
  Result := (n and PRI_KEY_FLAG) = PRI_KEY_FLAG;
end;

function IS_NOT_NULL(n: longword): boolean;
begin
  Result := (n and NOT_NULL_FLAG) = NOT_NULL_FLAG;
end;

function IS_BLOB(n: longword): boolean;
begin
  Result := (n and BLOB_FLAG) = BLOB_FLAG;
end;

function IS_NUM(t: longword): boolean;
begin
  Result := (t <= FIELD_TYPE_INT24) or (t = FIELD_TYPE_YEAR);
end;

function IS_NUM_FIELD(f: PMYSQL_FIELD): boolean;
begin
  Result := (f.flags and NUM_FLAG) = NUM_FLAG;
end;

function INTERNAL_NUM_FIELD(f: PMYSQL_FIELD): boolean;
begin
  Result := (((f._type <= FIELD_TYPE_INT24) and ((f._type <> FIELD_TYPE_TIMESTAMP) or (f.length = 14) or (f.length = 8))) or (f._type = FIELD_TYPE_YEAR));
end;

function mysql_reload(_mysql: PMYSQL): longint;
begin
  Result := mysql_refresh(_mysql, REFRESH_GRANT);
end;

function libmysql_load(name: pChar): byte;

  procedure assign_proc(var proc: FARPROC; name: pChar);
  begin
    proc := GetProcAddress(libmysql_handle, name);
    if proc = nil then libmysql_status := LIBMYSQL_INCOMPATIBLE;
  end;

begin
  libmysql_free;
  if name = nil then name := 'libmysql.dll';
  libmysql_handle := LoadLibrary(name);
  if libmysql_handle = 0 then libmysql_status := LIBMYSQL_MISSING
  else begin
    libmysql_status := LIBMYSQL_READY;
    assign_proc(@mysql_num_rows, 'mysql_num_rows');
    assign_proc(@mysql_num_fields, 'mysql_num_fields');
    assign_proc(@mysql_eof, 'mysql_eof');
    assign_proc(@mysql_fetch_field_direct, 'mysql_fetch_field_direct');
    assign_proc(@mysql_fetch_fields, 'mysql_fetch_fields');
    assign_proc(@mysql_row_tell, 'mysql_row_tell');
    assign_proc(@mysql_field_tell, 'mysql_field_tell');
    assign_proc(@mysql_field_count, 'mysql_field_count');
    assign_proc(@mysql_affected_rows, 'mysql_affected_rows');
    assign_proc(@mysql_insert_id, 'mysql_insert_id');
    assign_proc(@mysql_errno, 'mysql_errno');
    assign_proc(@mysql_error, 'mysql_error');
    assign_proc(@mysql_info, 'mysql_info');
    assign_proc(@mysql_thread_id, 'mysql_thread_id');
    assign_proc(@mysql_character_set_name, 'mysql_character_set_name');
    assign_proc(@mysql_init, 'mysql_init');
    {$IFDEF HAVE_OPENSSL}
    assign_proc(@mysql_ssl_set, 'mysql_ssl_set');
    assign_proc(@mysql_ssl_cipher, 'mysql_ssl_cipher');
    assign_proc(@mysql_ssl_clear, 'mysql_ssl_clear');
    {$ENDIF} // HAVE_OPENSSL
    assign_proc(@mysql_connect, 'mysql_connect');
    assign_proc(@mysql_change_user, 'mysql_change_user');
    assign_proc(@mysql_real_connect, 'mysql_real_connect');
    assign_proc(@mysql_close, 'mysql_close');
    assign_proc(@mysql_select_db, 'mysql_select_db');
    assign_proc(@mysql_query, 'mysql_query');
    assign_proc(@mysql_send_query, 'mysql_send_query');
    assign_proc(@mysql_read_query_result, 'mysql_read_query_result');
    assign_proc(@mysql_real_query, 'mysql_real_query');
    assign_proc(@mysql_create_db, 'mysql_create_db');
    assign_proc(@mysql_drop_db, 'mysql_drop_db');
    assign_proc(@mysql_shutdown, 'mysql_shutdown');
    assign_proc(@mysql_dump_debug_info, 'mysql_dump_debug_info');
    assign_proc(@mysql_refresh, 'mysql_refresh');
    assign_proc(@mysql_kill, 'mysql_kill');
    assign_proc(@mysql_ping, 'mysql_ping');
    assign_proc(@mysql_stat, 'mysql_stat');
    assign_proc(@mysql_get_server_info, 'mysql_get_server_info');
    assign_proc(@mysql_get_client_info, 'mysql_get_client_info');
    assign_proc(@mysql_get_host_info, 'mysql_get_host_info');
    assign_proc(@mysql_get_proto_info, 'mysql_get_proto_info');
    assign_proc(@mysql_list_dbs, 'mysql_list_dbs');
    assign_proc(@mysql_list_tables, 'mysql_list_tables');
    assign_proc(@mysql_list_fields, 'mysql_list_fields');
    assign_proc(@mysql_list_processes, 'mysql_list_processes');
    assign_proc(@mysql_store_result, 'mysql_store_result');
    assign_proc(@mysql_use_result, 'mysql_use_result');
    assign_proc(@mysql_options, 'mysql_options');
    assign_proc(@mysql_free_result, 'mysql_free_result');
    assign_proc(@mysql_data_seek, 'mysql_data_seek');
    assign_proc(@mysql_row_seek, 'mysql_row_seek');
    assign_proc(@mysql_field_seek, 'mysql_field_seek');
    assign_proc(@mysql_fetch_row, 'mysql_fetch_row');
    assign_proc(@mysql_fetch_lengths, 'mysql_fetch_lengths');
    assign_proc(@mysql_fetch_field, 'mysql_fetch_field');
    assign_proc(@mysql_escape_string, 'mysql_escape_string');
    assign_proc(@mysql_real_escape_string, 'mysql_real_escape_string');
    assign_proc(@mysql_debug, 'mysql_debug');
    assign_proc(@mysql_odbc_escape_string, 'mysql_odbc_escape_string');
    assign_proc(@myodbc_remove_escape, 'myodbc_remove_escape');
    assign_proc(@mysql_thread_safe, 'mysql_thread_safe');
  end;
  Result := libmysql_status;
end;

procedure libmysql_free;
begin
  if libmysql_handle <> 0 then FreeLibrary(libmysql_handle);
  libmysql_handle := 0;
  libmysql_status := LIBMYSQL_UNDEFINED;
end;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INITIALIZATION
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

begin
  {$IFNDEF DONT_LOAD_DLL}
  libmysql_load(nil);
  {$ENDIF} // DONT_LOAD_DLL
end;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FINALIZATION
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

begin
  libmysql_free;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I have a MySQL 4.1 server but whenever I call mysql_connect I get an access violation error. My username and password is correct. Any thoughts?

Comment: @bouncer: You would need to [debug that access violation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214458/debugging-access-violation-av-errors)

Answer (score 4):

[TMySQL5](http://www.torry.net/db/direct/mysql/MySQL5.zip) component provides fast access to MySQL server 5.0, the latest production server of MySQL. It only requires libmysql.dll, MySQL5.pas, and mysql.pas (thanks to Matthias Fichtner for making mysql.pas available).

At the moment this component only support up to 500 rows, and 10 fields. However, you can change this value in the statement Dataset: array[1..n, 1..m] to suit your requirement.

Only two data types available String and Integer, however, you can convert data using standard data conversion functions.

- Fully functional
- Source: Included
- Exe-Demo Included

Good through Delphi 2006

[Home page](http://tmysql5.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 4):

I use [Zeoslib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib) all the time to communicate with MySQL. It uses libmySQL.dll and I personally quite like it.

Eventhough it does a lot more than just wrapping libmysql, it's still pretty lightweight. You can even make it connect to libmysqld instead, to have a mysql engine embedded in your application (no need to connect to an exernal or local mysql server).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar unit which I developed for HeidiSQL:
https://code.google.com/p/heidisql/source/browse/trunk/source/dbconnection.pas .

It supports nearly all MySQL releases, even detects some other flavors as MariaDB, TokuDB, Percona, InfiniDB and InfoBright. Also, it supports Microsoft SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

The unit mainly contains 2 classes called TDBConnection and TDBQuery, and for both one derived class for each supported RDBMS.

However, the downside is it has some few dependencies to other units within the HeidiSQL sources, which you will need to break.

Comment: HeidiSQL moved back to Sourceforge, so here's the updated link to the Pascal file: https://sourceforge.net/p/heidisql/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/source/dbconnection.pas