# Delphi android app TEdit access violation

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have created a project under firemonkey on Delphi 10 Seattle and it works perfectly (Android, Win32 and Win64). I have had problems with that computer so I have used another which has Tokyo 10.2 (not with the update) and the latest version of the android SDK (latest API 7).

I have imported the project on Tokyo and compiled/built it.

When I try to build and run the project under win32/win64 it works perfectly but under Android the layout is a bit weird **^** and when I click on a TEdit the application crashes with an `Access violation`.

How can I solve this?

---

**^**: *weird* means that (android only) some TCircles are not well aligned and some TLayouts doesn't appear. I have had to position them again using the object inspector and it seems to work. Is this a compatibility fail?

When I touch the TEdit I have the error. Only on android, not on windows. This is not the first time and I have seen similar issues online as well. How can I avoid this?

Comment: This is very boring, I've had the same exact issue. Delete the TEdits, click 'Save All' and then drag-drop the TEdits from the object inspector. If you build and deploy the app it SHOULDN'T give you the access violation anymore. I don't know why this happens, but it worked for me...

Comment: Ok I'll try now and see what happen. Do you know why delphi has this problem?

Comment: "I don't know why this happens". This can be helpful > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214458/debugging-access-violation-errors

Comment: "*Tokyo 10.2 (not with the update)*" - Tokyo has major problems on Android without the hotfixes and updates. Please make sure you have everything installed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have solved my problem installing the patch. Thank you!